# Nonlinear alternating Euler sums

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, number-theory, riemann-zeta, euler-sums

Let $H_{n}^{(s)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{-s}$ and $\overline{H}_{n}^{(s)}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k+1}k^{-s}$. Flajolet - Salvy Theorem says that nonlinear Euler sum of the form
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}^{(p_{1})}H_{n}^{(p_{2})}\cdots H_{n}^{(p_{k})}}{n^{q}}
$$
can be reduced to zeta values and sums of lower order when $p_{1}+p_{2}+\dots+p_{k}+q$ and $k$ are the same parity. My question is, if they exist a version of this Theorem about nonlinear alternating Euler sums, that is sums of the form
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{H_{n}^{(p_{1})}H_{n}^{(p_{2})}\cdots H_{n}^{(p_{k})}\overline{H}_{n}^{(r_{1})}\overline{H}_{n}^{(r_{2})}\cdots \overline{H}_{n}^{(r_{l})}}{n^{q}},
$$
when $k+l\geq 2$?

Comment: Not even some particular cases?

Comment: Thank You! And what if we allow reducibility to alternating Euler sums of lower order? Is this also worth investigating?